# Question about changing the name of a function

Tags: python, function

I am doing some basics exercises in Python to really understand the basics of functions.

Now I have this exercise:

Assign a new name to the function, in order to be able to call the function with the new name:

```
def displayStudent(name, age):
    print(name, age)


displayStudent = showStudent

showStudent ('Emma', 30)
```

Like this I get an error saying showStudent is not defined

if a call the function displayStudent before changing the name I get the right result Emma 30

```
def displayStudent(name, age):
    print(name, age)

displayStudent ('Emma', 30)

displayStudent = showStudent

showStudent ('Emma', 30)
```

Would you be able to tell me why I need to call the function displayStudent before changing the name to showStudent. To me it does not make much sense. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `showStudent=displayStudent` .

Learn how to create variables here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp